# missing default argument on trailing parameter pack on clang

Tags: clang, metaprogramming

Clang complains about trailing parameter pack is not defaulted but as far as i know it is in standard and possible. Am i doing wrong or is it a bug of clang ?

It is my in repo, if you want to look at full source code, [it is here](https://github.com/OzanCansel/speech/blob/master/src/speech/tcp/tcp_server.h#L55).

Clang version is :

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Code is :

```
template<typename... T>
auto make_server ( const QHostAddress &address = QHostAddress::Any, speech::port p = speech::port ( 0 ), T... generators) -> std::unique_ptr<tcp_server<decltype ( generators )...>>
{
     using server_type = tcp_server<decltype ( generators )...>;
     return std::unique_ptr<server_type> ( new server_type ( address, p, generators... ) );
}
```

Error message is :

```
error: missing default argument on parameter 'generators'
auto make_server ( const QHostAddress &address = QHostAddress::Any, speech::port p = speech::port ( 0 ), T... generators) -> std::unique_ptr<tcp_server<decltype ( generators )...>>
```

Comment: Can you show the code where this function is called?

Comment: Same problem here... No solution posted?

Comment: As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64462437/why-clang-missing-default-argument-on-parameter-pack-error) it is a clang 10 bug and is fixed on clang 11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why clang missing default argument on parameter pack error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64462437/why-clang-missing-default-argument-on-parameter-pack-error)