# Why clang missing default argument on parameter pack error?

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

When I use clang (10.0.1) to compile that:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename ...Args>
void f( int a = 4, Args&&... aArgs )
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    f( 1, 2 );
    return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
main.cpp:4:30: error: missing default argument on parameter 'aArgs'
```

But standard say about [default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments):

> In a function declaration, after a parameter with a default argument,
> all subsequent parameters must have a default argument supplied in this or a previous declaration from the same scope
> (since c++11) ...unless the parameter was expanded from a parameter pack
> or be a function parameter pack.

It is a clang bug?

hint: I try it on gcc and works fine

Comment: I think is same error on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57309103/missing-default-argument-on-trailing-parameter-pack-on-clang but simplified case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23029.

It's fixed in clang 11: https://reviews.llvm.org/rGb5f2c4e45b8d54063051e6955cef0bbb7b6ab0f8

Comment: I was changing my compiler to get more errors but my project dont compile with clang due to that...

Comment: @IsaacPascual That's unfortunate. You could try splitting the function template up in two if you'd like to continue with clang: https://godbolt.org/z/aTrv7q